# Cocoapod: Why Xcode build process try to find the library which has been already removed from my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

Thank you always for all of your knowledge.

I have checked my issue in StackOverflow and found similar issues but could not find my case specifically. Greatly appreciated If some of you could advise my situation.

**My environment;**

xcode: Version 6.0.1, 
ios target: IOS 8, 
code: OBjective-C

I opened my project by Myproject.xcworkspace.

**Issue;**

I used Cocoapod to install some libraries. Here was the code in podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'
pod 'AFNetworking', "~> 2.0"
pod 'KissXML'
```

Then in terminal.

```
pod install
```

After all I knew I did not need some of these libraries, then modify podfile like below.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'
```

Then in terminal.

```
pod update
```

I found AFNetworking and KissXML are removed from my project.

However when I did Product->Archive in Xcode, the following error occurred.

**ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

and

**ld: library not found for -lPods-KissXML
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Just Run went succeeded but Archive came up with those error.

Why build process still try to find libraries which has been already removed?

Thank you always.

Answer (score 2):

open your project build setting ,may be there are some link or other library link or library path in it . Your remove it .

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, and your advise solved my problem! I will add own answer what I did to solve it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

By @Feng Lin's advise, I solved my issue, so I answer my question for your knowledge.

Target -> Build Setting -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags

Click text, and remove those you have [image]already removed from podfile. In my case, AFNetworking and KissXML.

Done!